# Swagger/Swashbuckle doc generation only for API controllers within an MVC core app

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

We have an ASP.NET MVC Core application with regular MVC controllers. In addition, we have a subfolder within the Controllers folder called "API", containing a small number of API controllers.

We're using the `.IncludeXmlComments` method within `.AddSwaggerGen` to pick up the XML documentation within our project.

However, it's also picking up the XML for all our regular controllers too.

Is there a way to filter out the 'regular' controllers, or otherwise select only API controllers for inclusion in the swagger documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [DocInclusionPredicate](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#customize-the-action-selection-process), it should solve your problem

```cs
// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
    {
        if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)) return false;

        // Check if methodInfo is in the right assembly
        // or has the right namespace or version etc.
        bool isMethodIncluded = /* true or false */;

        return isMethodIncluded ;
    });
);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. In my case, the solution I wanted was this:

`return methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiControllerAttribute>(true).Any();`

So if the controller is decorated with the ApiControllerAttribute, then include in the Swagger docs, else ignore.

Works great.